# How to get rid of global data in a Compojure application

Tags: clojure, compojure

On http://mindbat.com/2013/03/clojurewest-2013-day-one-notes/ there is a note that reads:

- def’ing refs and atoms at the top level is basically global mutable state via singletons, please avoid
- recommend using constructor functions to *return* the state variables you want to use, then pass that state along to each function

I think this is good advice but I am not totally sure how to implement this in a Ring/Compojure application.  Can anyone give a concrete example of how this would work?

I'm specially interested how to combine `defroutes`, `init` and `app` together this way and get rid of global variables in that scope.

Answer (score 5):

What I understand from Stuart's talk is something like this:

```
(ns state.core)

(defn create-user-module [] (atom []))

(defn add-user [module user]
  (swap! module conj user))

(defn get-users [module]
  @module)
```

Now there is no global state in your "core" as the functions that manipulate the state expect to get it as a parameter. These allows easy testing as you can create a new instance of the "user-module" for each test. Also, the clients of this module shouldn't care about what they get in the create-user-module function, they should just pass it around without inspecting it, that way you can change the user module implementation whenever you want. Stuart also talks about creating protocols for those modules if you are going to have more than one implementation.

Trying to answer your question, a ring adapter is just a function of 1 param, and compojure is just a routing library, so you could create a web-app using closures like:

```
(ns state.web
  (:use compojure.core)
  (:require [state.core :as core]))

(defn web-module [user-module]
  (routes
   (GET "/all" [] (core/get-users user-module))))
```

Now you can call the web-module to create a webapp, passing as a parameter the dependencies needed. Of course you still need somebody to create the web app with the correct user-modules, so you just need a "main" function that wires everything together:

```
(ns state.main
  (:require state.core
            state.web)
  (:use ring.adapter.jetty))

(defn start []
  (let [user-module (state.core/create-user-module)
        web-module (state.web/web-module user-module)]
    (run-jetty web-module {:port 3000 :join? false})))

(defn stop [app]
    (.stop app))
```

`start` will be called from your app `main` method. This just means that you need to switch to the lein-run plugin.

Now, given that you are asking about `init` (from the lein ring plugin I assume), I guess that you plan to deploy your webapp in a container. As the lein ring plugin has to work within the java servlet fw constraints and that the handler ends up compiled to a java servlet, the best that you can probably do is something like:

```
(ns state.web
  (:use compojure.core)
  (:require [state.core :as core]))

(def module-deps (atom {})

(defn init-app [] (swap! module-deps conj [:user-module (core/create-user-module)]))

(defroutes web-module []
   (GET "/all" [] (core/get-users (:user-module @module-deps))))
```

This still means that your core namespace is easy to test, but you still have global state in the web namespace, but I think that is "properly" encapsulated and probably is good enough if you have to use a java container.

And this is just another argument of why libraries are "better" than frameworks :)

Answer (score 2):

There are many cases where you need global state hence you cannot avoid it, what you can do is **manage** it properly and I guess that's what the 2 points talk about:

Not a good way:

```
(ns data)
(def users (atom []))

(ns pages)
(defn home []
    (do-something data/@users)

(defn save []
    (let [u @users]
       (swap! data/users ....)
```

Good way:

```
(ns data)
(def- users (atom []))
(defn get-users [] @users)
(defn update-user [user] (swap! @users ...))

(ns pages)
; use the functions exposed by data ns to interact with data rather then poking the atom directly.
```

Basically all the access to any type of state should be abstracted away from other parts of the application. All your business logic function should take the state as parameter and return new state rather than picking the state themselves and updating it directly.

Comment: @hsestupin: Is that a question OR affirmation :)

Comment: Affirmation ofc. I meant I totally agree with that kind of approach when state couldn't be changed by direct reference.

Comment: That looks like encapsulated global state, which is still bad. See http://vimeo.com/46163090 for the talk.

Comment: @dAni Can you please mention what is suggest in the talk, specifically  the solution (rather than just saying it is bad)

Comment: @Ankur sorry I assumed that St3fan hadn't seen the presentation but just the summary, so the full presentation from Stuart would be enough explanation (30 mins!) about what it meant. See my response for a full explanation about how to apply it to compojure.